# Automatically create folder to mount remote folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, mount, nas

I'm using the CrashPlan client to backup my computer data to a local NAS. Unfortunately I can't directly put a remote folder in CrashPlan, I have to mount it in a local folder. But sometimes it can happens my NAS was offline for various reason, when it comes CrashPlan backup my data to the folder I use to mount the backup remote folder and so fill my hard disk.

Is there any way to automatically create this local folder only when the remote folder is mounted ? And so don't exists when the NAS is offline to avoid backup on local disk.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on serverfault, simply make the folder immutable when unmounted with `chattr +i /media/folder`

https://serverfault.com/a/314022/138329